# How to run an infinite loop in Android without freezing the UI?

Tags: android

I'm creating and android program which needs to to continuously keep sending data over the bluetooth now I use something like this:

```
for(;;)
{
//send message
}
```

though this works it freezes my UI and app how can I implement the same without freezing my UI?

I am sure that the app is sending the data as I monitor the data.

Comment: use [`AsyncTask`](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=AsyncTask)

Comment: Do you actually have something that needs to be displayed on the screen? If not use a Service. If so use AsyncTask as @AdilSoomro says.

Comment: Another good (yet lengthy) resource would be http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Create the **Service** that uses `Timer` and  `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 7):

Put your loop in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) with separate Thread or just in another Thread beside your Activity. Never do heavy work, infinte loops, or blocking calls in your main (UI) Thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kotlin then you can use coroutines.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.4"
```

initialize a job variable `job:Job` globally
then do:

```kotlin
job = 
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    while (job.isActive) {
        //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Do `job.cancel()` when you want your loop to stop

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the work into another thread (other than the UI thread), to prevent ANR.

```
new Thread( new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            //do work here
        }
    }).start();
```

The above is a quick and dirty method, The preferred method in most cases is using AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Start an IntentService which will create a background thread for you to run your Service in.   Call Looper.prepare() as @YellowJK suggests, but then call Looper.loop() when you need your program to wait for something to happen so the Service isn't killed.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
   Looper.prepare();
   //Do work here
   //Once work is done and you are waiting for something such as a Broadcast Receiver or GPS Listenr call Looper.loop() so Service is not killed
   Looper.loop();
}
```